# Knowledge Article Self relationship

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have a requirement on knowledge articles, to display on the visualforce page and also have to give self relationship to the same article type. ,That means one article can be associated with multiple articles like child and parent . Since saleforce has not provided to create a lookup to the article, so can any one please let me know what is the best way to achieve this functionality.

Note:
In visualforce page, if i click on one article i should be navigated to the next page which contains list of related articles under that article record.

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 0):

According conversation on Salesforce Community this functionality is currently under review by SF product team. Currently you can refer to articles through "Smart Links" in the rich text fields, but I hope such useful thing soon will be added. Here is [link to Idea details](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007obp) on Salesforce Community.

Also there is approach to implement such functionality with Case related list, but it looks like no very beautiful way. For more details see [this discussion](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006xyyAAA).